# Axios post request with typescript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to add typescript to my current project, so after using it with Axios `post` request, I am facing an issue.

Use case is that I want to send `email` `firstname` `lastname` and `password` in my post request and in response I want to get `accessToken`

Here is the code below:

```
export interface UserRegistrationModel {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

export const register = async (user: UserRegistrationModel) => {
  const { data } = await http.post<UserRegistrationModel>("/users", user);
  return data;
};
```

This is my function called after I submit the registration form like:

```
register(values)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.accessToken);
    setLoading(false);
  }).catch(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
```

So here in my `then` block when I try to access `accessToken` by `data.acessToken` throws error.

> Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'UserRegistrationModel'

So I tried to define a new Interface named `AuthModel` but then when I assign it to data like:

```
export interface AuthModel {
  accessToken: string
}

 register(values)
   .then((data:AuthModel) => {
     console.log(data.accessToken);
     setLoading(false);
   }).catch(() => {
     setLoading(false);
     setSubmitting(false);
     setStatus("Registration process has broken");
   });
```

It says:

> Argument of type '(data: AuthModel) => void' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(value: UserRegistrationModel) => void |
> PromiseLike'.   Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are
> incompatible.
> Property 'accessToken' is missing in type 'UserRegistrationModel' but required in type 'AuthModel'.

Below is the `axios` config in anyone wants to see:

`http.ts`:

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";

enum StatusCode {
  Unauthorized = 401,
  Forbidden = 403,
  TooManyRequests = 429,
  InternalServerError = 500,
}

const headers: Readonly<Record<string, string | boolean>> = {
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
};

// We can use the following function to inject the JWT token through an interceptor
// We get the `accessToken` from the localStorage that we set when we authenticate
const injectToken = (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
  try {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    if (token != null) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};

class Http {
  private instance: AxiosInstance | null = null;

  private get http(): AxiosInstance {
    return this.instance != null ? this.instance : this.initHttp();
  }

  initHttp() {
    const http = axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://api.example.com",
      headers,
      withCredentials: true,
    });

    http.interceptors.request.use(injectToken, (error) =>
      Promise.reject(error)
    );

    http.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,
      (error) => {
        const { response } = error;
        return this.handleError(response);
      }
    );

    this.instance = http;
    return http;
  }

  request<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(
    config: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.request(config);
  }

  get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(
    url: string,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.get<T, R>(url, config);
  }

  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.post<T, R>(url, data, config);
  }

  put<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.put<T, R>(url, data, config);
  }

  delete<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(
    url: string,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.delete<T, R>(url, config);
  }

  // Handle global app errors
  // We can handle generic app errors depending on the status code
  private handleError(error: any) {
    const { status } = error;

    switch (status) {
      case StatusCode.InternalServerError: {
        // Handle InternalServerError
        break;
      }
      case StatusCode.Forbidden: {
        // Handle Forbidden
        break;
      }
      case StatusCode.Unauthorized: {
        // Handle Unauthorized
        break;
      }
      case StatusCode.TooManyRequests: {
        // Handle TooManyRequests
        break;
      }
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}

export const http = new Http();
```

Answer (score 9):

There is an ability to set different types to input an output data (axios definitions):

```
post<T = never, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, data?: T, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<T>): Promise<R>;
```

So, in your case it would be something like:

```
export interface UserRegistrationModel {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

export const register = async (user: UserRegistrationModel) => {
  const { data } = await http.post<UserRegistrationModel, AxiosResponse<{ accessToken: string }>>("/users", user);
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your register function to:

```
export const register = async (user: UserRegistrationModel) => {
  const { data } = await http.post<AuthModel>("/users", user);
  return data;
};
```

Also inside your class, the type for `post` should be:

```
post<T = any>(
    url: string,
    data?: T,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<T> {
    return this.http.post(url, data, config);
}
```

---

> Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'UserRegistrationModel

You set the return type for `data` to be `UserRegistrationModel`, and typescript is telling you that `accessToken` does not exist on that type. This should be obvious from your definition.

> Argument of type '(data: AuthModel) => void' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(value: UserRegistrationModel) => void |
> PromiseLike'. Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Property 'accessToken' is missing in type 'UserRegistrationModel' but
> required in type 'AuthModel'.

You are trying to pass a function which expects `AuthModel` as the only argument, but once again your `register` function will pass `UserRegistrationModel` to that function. Typescript is just informing you of this.

Comment: tried that it says "Argument of type 'UserRegistrationModel' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AuthModel'.
  Property 'accessToken' is missing in type 'UserRegistrationModel' but required in type 'AuthModel'."

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai See the updated answer. You need to change the type for `post`

Comment: still didnt worked :(, well m sure there is some issue with post function inside class as when i am using direct axios without creating instances it's working

Answer (score 0):

This tricky type assertion works for me, component code:

```
let response = (await UserService.LoginUser(
  email,
  password
)) as unknown as AxiosResponse<JwtResponse>;
```

Post method:
Where T is generic type and AxiosResponse is overriden to my interfaces (just rewrite, no changes yet)

```
post: async function <T>(URL: string, data: any) {
return await client.post<T, AxiosResponse<T>>(URL, data);
},
```

Then, in services I basically return resolved promise like this:

```
return await API.post<JwtResponse>(`api/User/login`, {
  Email: email,
  Password: passowrd,
})
  .then((result: AxiosResponse<JwtResponse>) => {
    CookieService.SetCookie("jwt", result.data);
    return result;
})
```